# What's the simplest/easiest backend solution for Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, rapid-prototyping

I'm a total Ember.js noob, and need to get my head around the backend considerations, which it seems very few tutorials cover as of yet. For rapid prototyping, what's the simplest/easiest backend setup? I see a few ember-rails tutorials out there, but is it really necessary to build a whole Rails backend? Can something like Parse do the backend work via an Ember Data adapter? Would that end up being just as much work as doing it in Rails? Should I be looking at Node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I too am noob. I tried ember with ember model and parse. I was able to do it with [Ember model parse adapter](https://github.com/ebryn/ember-model-parse-adapter) but was not able to do non-embeded relationship. I think ember model is good.

Comment: I saw some activity on the issue I raised on ember model github for non embedded relationship. It say closed. I did not test it myself

Answer (score 1):

In short, If you want to get benefits of Ember-data, any backend that provides custom routing is useful. As EmberJS has Yehuda Katz, it has been developed considering Ruby On Rails and you can trust it. But i did use EmberJS with other technologies like NodeJS, Laravel, Play and they are equally good.

If you are not using Ember-data, it doesn't matter much what you gonna use for back end. You can always use Rest calls to get the data and create Models.

Answer (score 1):

I Think Rails is the best back end option to use with ember.As both ember and rails are architecture in same fashion it will be easy to learn and deploy both as a pack.Also ember data provides a good abstraction to use with ember .